# django "ATOMIC_REQUESTS" 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'

Tags: django

I found a strange phenomenon. When I added ATOMIC_REQUESTS:True to the database in the settings, django crashed when connecting to MySql. It kept prompting "Lost connection to MySQL server during query". Change ATOMIC_REQUESTS to False and it can be used normally. Someone Encountered similar problems?

Djano 3.1
Mysql 5.7
centos6.9

```
[pid: 30542|app: 0|req: 1/2] {44 vars in 1024 bytes} [Fri Mar 12 09:49:19 2021] OPTIONS /sap/base/v1/user/?page=1 => generated 0 bytes in 2116 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 10 headers in 481 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.001) SELECT `Base_user`.`id`, `Base_user`.`last_login`, `Base_user`.`is_superuser`, `Base_user`.`first_name`, `Base_user`.`last_name`, `Base_user`.`email`, `Base_user`.`is_staff`, `Base_user`.`is_active`, `Base_user`.`date_joined`, `Base_user`.`username`, `Base_user`.`password` FROM `Base_user` WHERE `Base_user`.`id` = '38bddf2e182911eb8f5e00163e0ffd5b' LIMIT 21; args=('38bddf2e182911eb8f5e00163e0ffd5b',)
/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/pagination.py:200: UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'SapBase.models.User'> QuerySet.
  paginator = self.django_paginator_class(queryset, page_size)
(0.005) SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count` FROM `SapBase_user`; args=()
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
[pid: 30543|app: 0|req: 1/3]  {44 vars in 1021 bytes} [Fri Mar 12 09:49:19 2021] OPTIONS /sap/base/v1/group/all/ => generated 0 bytes in 2085 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 10 headers in 481 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.001) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.002) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.002) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.002) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.002) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.002) SELECT `Base_user`.`id`, `Base_user`.`last_login`, `Base_user`.`is_superuser`, `Base_user`.`first_name`, `Base_user`.`last_name`, `Base_user`.`email`, `Base_user`.`is_staff`, `Base_user`.`is_active`, `Base_user`.`date_joined`, `Base_user`.`username`, `Base_user`.`password` FROM `Base_user` WHERE `Base_user`.`id` = '38bddf2e182911eb8f5e00163e0ffd5b' LIMIT 21; args=('38bddf2e182911eb8f5e00163e0ffd5b',)
(0.003) SELECT `auth_group`.`id`, `auth_group`.`name` FROM `auth_group` ORDER BY `auth_group`.`id` ASC; args=()
[pid: 30543|app: 0|req: 2/4]  {44 vars in 1256 bytes} [Fri Mar 12 09:49:21 2021] GET /sap/base/v1/group/all/ => generated 938 bytes in 168 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 9 headers in 283 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
Internal Server Error: /sap/base/v1/user/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/python3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/python3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 232, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 266, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/jay/fs_work_django_dev/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
[pid: 30544|app: 0|req: 2/5]  {44 vars in 1259 bytes} [Fri Mar 12 09:49:21 2021] GET /sap/base/v1/user/?page=1 => generated 101317 bytes in 555 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 8 headers in 263 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.001) SELECT `Base_user`.`id`, `Base_user`.`last_login`, `Base_user`.`is_superuser`, `Base_user`.`first_name`, `Base_user`.`last_name`, `Base_user`.`email`, `Base_user`.`is_staff`, `Base_user`.`is_active`, `Base_user`.`date_joined`, `Base_user`.`username`, `Base_user`.`password` FROM `Base_user` WHERE `Base_user`.`id` = '38bddf2e182911eb8f5e00163e0ffd5b' LIMIT 21; args=('38bddf2e182911eb8f5e00163e0ffd5b',)
(0.002) SELECT `employee`.`id`, `employee`.`employee_id`, `employee`.`name`, `employee`.`alias`, `employee`.`mobile`, `employee`.`department`, `employee`.`email`, `employee`.`position`, `employee`.`gender`, `employee`.`avatar`, `employee`.`telephone`, `employee`.`enable`, `employee`.`status`, `employee`.`address` FROM `employee`; args=()
[pid: 30541|app: 0|req: 1/6]  {44 vars in 1282 bytes} [Fri Mar 12 09:49:20 2021] GET /work/info/v1/employee/all_employee/ => generated 20343 bytes in 1273 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 9 headers in 285 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

```py
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret.pop('base_user')
        try:
            ret['employee'] = WeChatWork_serializers.EmployeeSerializer(instance.employee).data
        except Exception as identifier:
            print('identifier', identifier)
            ret['employee'] = {'name': 'none', 'employee_id': '', 'departments': ['']}
        ret['super'] = instance.base_user.is_superuser
        sql = '''
                SELECT
                    `auth_group`.`id`,
                    `auth_group`.`name` 
                FROM
                    `auth_group`
                    INNER JOIN `Base_user_groups` ON ( `auth_group`.`id` = `Base_user_groups`.`group_id` ) 
                WHERE
                    `Base_user_groups`.`user_id` = '%s'
                ''' % instance.base_user.id.hex
        with connections['default'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            data = dictfetchall(cursor)
        group = ','.join([str(i["id"]) for i in data])
        if group:
            sql = '''
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        concat( T3.app_label, '.', T3.model, '.', T2.codename ) AS perm
                    FROM
                        auth_group T0
                        LEFT JOIN auth_group_permissions T1 ON T0.id = T1.group_id
                        LEFT JOIN auth_permission T2 ON T1.permission_id = T2.id
                        LEFT JOIN django_content_type T3 ON T2.content_type_id = T3.id
                    WHERE
                        T0.id IN (
                        %s)
                ''' % group
            with connections['default'].cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(sql)
                data = dictfetchall(cursor)
        else:
            data = []
        prems = [i['perm'] for i in data]
        prems += [(prem.content_type.app_label + '.' + prem.content_type.model + '.' + prem.codename) for prem in
                  instance.base_user.user_permissions.all()]
        ret['prems'] = list(set(prems))
        return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how atomic and raw SQL interacts but I guess the problem is  coming from closing the connection yourself. You're doing

```py
with connections['default'].cursor() as cursor:
```

That basically means when `with` finished, close the connection. Django wants to commit the transaction at end of request but connection is not there. Replace it with

```py
cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
```

On a side note, be careful when doing raw queries, you're open to SQL injection. Passing parameters to `execute` instead of string formatting will mitigate that.

---

Old answer:

You need to debug it more, e.g. check MySQL logs.

The only promising reason that comes to my mind is you're opening a transaction but wait a lot before sending anything/commit so you get a timeout and MySQL closes the connection.

Comment: I added an error message and part of the code to the problem description. I tried to modify part of the code it locates. This problem still exists when I change the orm to the SQL statement. I still have no clue.